# Sharepoint 2013 Page Not found on Variations Site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a site deployed to Sharepoint and Variations enabled.

```
http://localsite/Pages/Home.aspx
http://localsite/en-gb/Pages/Home.aspx
http://localsite/de-de/Pages/Home.aspx
```

I have a 404 page in my root site entitled PageNotFoundError.aspx. I have copied this page into the Pages folders of each variation site but when I hit a page that doesn't exist, its naviagting to

```
http://localsite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx
```

instead of

```
http://localsite/de-de/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx
```

Any ideas how I make it hit the variations version of the error page? Is this a setting somewhere in the Site Settings of each language/variation?